# Как получить картинку из Canvas?

Tags: jquery, canvas, javascript

Например, из участка кода нужно вытащить картинку и вставить ее в src:

```
var canvas = $(this).closest('.preview').find('canvas').clone();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сохранения изображения существует только один метод toDataURL у самого canvas, он преобразует изображенное в формат data url.

```
picture.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

**Обновление**

Я же написал, что эта функция есть у canvas, а не у объекта jquery, в котором он находится))

```
var canvas = $(this).closest('.preview').find('canvas').clone();
var dataImage = canvas[0].toDataURL();
```

**Обновление 2**

Ох, это что-то вроде адреса URL, но который сам же и хранит ответ без запросов. Просто присвойте ее картинке как адрес `<img src="%вставить%" />`. Ну или кодом:

```
$('картинка').attr("src",dataImage);
```

Опять редактор ссылку не воспринимает... Тогда текстом:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL

Comment: Ругается так: ncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                 `var image = $(this).closest('.preview').find('canvas').clone();
    alert(image.toDataURL());`

Comment: Это будет картинка или же путь к картинке? Как ее отобразить?

Comment: В этом и дело - что не работает так - вижу, что в SRC есть data, но картинка не отображается.

Comment: Угу, понятно, при клонировании объекта canvas его содержимое не сохраняется. Если убрать clone(), то все будет нормально. Если нужен клон, то придется поступить иначе: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318565/any-way-to-clone-html5-canvas-element-with-its-content